# How to use .then() in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm a complete beginner in `node.js`. I've just read we can use `.then()` function for executing several functions in particular order. I was going to write the code this way:

```
function one(){
  console.log("one")
}
function two(){
  console.log("two")
}
function three(){
  console.log("three")
}
one().then(two()).then(three())
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\chat\test.js:10:6)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:502:3
```

Comment: `then` is being used for [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: This only works for Promises and for functions that return Promises. It's not something that is available with all methods that Node has.

Comment: You don't need to use `then` when dealing with synchronous functions (and those in your post are). If you write `one(); two(); three()`, they will be executed exactly in this order.

Comment: Go read about Javascript promises. If you do a simple search on .then() on google or stackoverflow you will have TONS of resources. Research before posting a question, show what you learned, and then if you can't figure it out, then post a question.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`.then` is a method that exists on Promises and is a mechanism for code synchronization. Your code is not asynchronous, so you wouldn't need to use promises.  You can just call

```
one();
two();
three();
```

If your code does something asynchronous, then you can use promises and `.then`. Asynchronous operations are things like reading/writing files, http requests, timers, and many more.

Just as an example, we can use the built in `Promise` to create our own asynchronous operations:

*I don't recommend you do this normally. We're just using it as an example. In most cases you can call functions that already return promises for you*.

```
function one() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log("one");
    resolve();
  });
}

function two() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log("two");
    resolve();
  });
}

function three(){
   console.log("three")
}

one().then(() => two()).then(() => three());
```

Also note that when you use `.then`, you need to pass a *callback*. `two()` calls the `two` function immediately, so it's not the same as `() => two()`.

---

Next, you can often use `async`/`await` instead of `.then` which I think makes your code easier to reason about in most cases.

```
async function run() {
  await one();
  await two();
  three();
}
run();
```

This is the same as the second example rewritten to use `await` instead of `.then`. You can think of everything after `await` as being inside of a `.then` chained to the expression after `await`.

---

Finally, you should handle errors by either chaining `.catch` to the promises or using the normal `try`/`catch` inside of `async` functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your detailed explanation

Comment: I am really confused by this response.

Comment: @user10664542 can you be more specific about what is confusing you?

Answer (score 5):

.then only works if the function returns a Promise. Promises are used for asynchronous tasks, so you can wait on something before doing something else.

```js
function one(){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('one')
      resolve();
     }, 1000);
  });
}

function two(){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('two')
      resolve();
     }, 1000);
  });
}

function three(){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('three')
      resolve();
     }, 1000);
  });
}

one().then(two).then(three);
```

You can use the resolve (and second argument reject) to return a result to the next .then or .catch:

```js
function one(){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('one');
     }, 1000);
  });
}

function two(){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('two');
     }, 1000);
  });
}

function three(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      reject(new Error('three'));
     }, 1000);
  });
}

one()
  .then((msg) => {
    console.log('first msg:', msg);
    return two();
  })
  .then((msg) => {
    console.log('second msg:', msg);
    return three();
  })
  .then((msg) => {
    // This one is never called because three() rejects with an error and is caught below.
    console.log('third msg:', msg);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Something bad happened:', error.toString());
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Then is usually used in the context of Promises. You could start reading more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Answer (score 0):

the .then() function is used for the PROMISE (so for async function ) when you need to KNOW WHEN IT'S FINISHED (and it is finished ok .. or KO ) ..so you have

```
MYASYNCFUNCTION().then(function(response({

 //do what you want when it's finish and everything ok .. with the result

}).catch(function(error){
 // it's finshed but with error
})
```

IN your example .. you don't have .then() function cause they're simple function .. but if you want to have it (i don't know why . they've not async stuff inside .. but you can)

so

// install it via npm install promise

```
var Promise = require('promise');

function one(){
var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  resolve('one');
  });
});

}
```

and then

```
one().then(function(resp){ console.log(resp) })
```

Hope it helps you!!

Answer (score -1):

`.then()` is for [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You also want to pass the function, not its return type as the `.then()` parameter. To make your example work, try:

```
function one(){
  return Promise.resolve(console.log("one"));
}
function two(){
  return Promise.resolve(console.log("two"));
}
function three(){
  return Promise.resolve(console.log("three"));
}

one()
  .then(two)
  .then(three)
  .catch(error => { 
    console.error('uhoh');
  });
```

Also, while this may work for your example. You won't normally use `Promise.resolve()`. You'll find it more typical to see the constructor used:

```
function func(a, b) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!a || !b) return reject('missing required arguments');
    return resolve(a + b);
  }
}
```

Calling `reject` on an error condition, and `resolve` on success. Rejections are routed to the first `.catch()`. I encourage you to read up on Promises in the link above.