# (...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to fix the error on code below, can someone help me please?. The code is written on `JS(NodeJs)`. The error is this `(...).then is not a function`. Thanks.

```
try {
  var decoded = jwt.decode(JWTToken, { complete: true });
  var audience = decoded.payload.aud;

  return db.checkAudience(audience).then(ehClient => {
    if (ehClient == true) {
      return db.getCreditsGeneral(sgecode, collections, year).then(total => {
        let result = [];
        total.forEach(item => {
          result.push({
            collection: item.Sistema,
            levelType: item.idNivelEnsino,
            grade: item.codPortal
          });
        });
        return result;
      });
    } else {
      return "not authorized";
    }
  });
} catch (err) {
  return { erro: err.message };
}
```

Comment: We will need more information. At which line is this error thrown?

Comment: is `checkAudience` a promise?

Comment: Either the function checkAudience or getCreditsGeneral doesn't return a promise.

Comment: so what is db.checkAudience? is it  a promise

Comment: Oh sorry, the problem is on catch(err). I checked the audience and is null, so the flow goes to catcherr) and the error appears.

Comment: So, then it is solved? `checkAudience()` cannot return `null` if you're calling the `then` function on it.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49033694/how-to-use-then-in-node-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49033694/how-to-use-then-in-node-js) I'm sure that you can do it without outside help

Comment: @LucasCaladoCerbelo please add the answer. So other people who search for the quesstion will get a solution

Comment: @LucasCaladoCerbelo can you share the `checkAudience()` function?