# javascript callback pattern using simple example

Tags: javascript, callback

I've been unable to find a simple example of a javascript callback pattern for my purpose and an answer to the following question would be very helpful.

Supposing I've 2 functions which each display an alert:

```
function hello1() {
 setTimeout(function(){
    alert("hello1");
   }, 500); 
  } 

function hello2() {
 alert("hello2");
  }
```

if I'm using this function,

```
function saythehellos()
{
hello1();
hello2();
}
```

the alert "hello2" will display first followed by the alert "hello1"

How can I change the function `saythehellos()` using a callback pattern so that the alert "hello1" is displayed first followed by the alert "hello2"?

Comment: Have a look at '.then' -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49033694/how-to-use-then-in-node-js#49033851

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ES7's [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax with a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). In your `hello1()` method you can return a promise which will `alert()` and then `resolve` to indicate that your `hello1` method is complete. Then `saythehellos()` will wait for `hello1()` to `resolve` (as we are using the `await` keyword) and then it will continue to execute `hello2()`:

```js
function hello1() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert("hello1");
      resolve();
    }, 500);
  });

}

function hello2() {
  alert("hello2");
}


async function saythehellos() { // make async as we want to use await within this method
  await hello1();
  hello2();
}

saythehellos();
```

Alternatively, if you're looking for something a little more browser compatible, you can use the `.then` callback on the returned promise from `hello1()` (which is essentially what `async/await` is doing under the hood). The `.then` callback will be fired when the returned `promise` has resolved:

```js
function hello1() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert("hello1");
      resolve();
    }, 500);
  });

}

function hello2() {
  alert("hello2");
}


function saythehellos() {
  hello1().then(function(result) {
    hello2();
  });
}

saythehellos();
```

Answer (score 2):

As per quetion, you can define a callback pattern as per the following, define callback function as an argument.

```js
function hello1(callback) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    alert("hello1");
    callback();
  }, 500); 
} 

function hello2() {
  alert("hello2");
}

hello1(hello2);
```

In `ES6` a special syntax to work with promises in a more comfortable fashion, called `async/await`. It’s surprisingly easy to understand and use. you can also use it. In behind the scene, `async/await` work as `callback`

> Edited as per request:

You can do it by the `third function(saythehellos)` as per the following chain.

```js
function hello1(callback) {
  
 setTimeout(function(){
    alert("hello1");
    callback();
  }, 500); 
}

function hello2(callback) {
   alert("hello2");
   callback();
}

function saythehellos(callback) {
    hello1(function() {
        hello2(function() {
            callback();
        });
    });
}

saythehellos(function(){alert('all done')});
```

Comment: thank you (and +1) but can I do this entirely within the "saythehellos()" function?

Answer (score 1):

The simple callback way is:

```
function hello1(hello2Callback) {
   alert("hello1");
   hello2Callback && hello2Callback();
}

hello1(function() {
  alert("hello2");
});
```

I hope this will help you. The callback function is a function that is passed as an argument. So, when calling hello1(), I am passing a complete function definition. This argument is called callback function.

The Promise is a new efficient and clean way on handling callbacks. You can check Javascript Promise over Google.

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach to achieve this:

```
function Hello1(){
   setTimeOut(onTimeOutRaise,500)
}

function onTimeOutRaise(){
  alert("Hello1");
  Hello2();
}
function Hello2(){
 alert("Hello2")
}
```

Here "**onTimeOutRaise**" itself a callback.