# How to move the code to set ut DB and collection out from my file and just requre it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arangodb, arangojs

So, let's say I have this code that works perfectly.

```js
const {
  Database
} = require("arangojs");

var db = new Database({
  url: "http://localhost:8529"
});

const database_name = "cool_database";

db.useBasicAuth("username", "password123");
db.listDatabases()
  .then(names => {
    if (names.indexOf(database_name) > -1) {
      db.useDatabase(database_name);
      db.get();
    } else {
      db.createDatabase(database_name)
        .then(() => {
          db.useDatabase(database_name);
          db.collection("my-collection").create();
        });
    }
  });


const collection = db.collection("my-collection");

const getJobFromQueue = () => {
  return db.query({
      query: "FOR el IN @@collection FILTER DATE_TIMESTAMP(el.email.sendAfter) < DATE_NOW() AND el.status != 'processed' AND el.status != 'failed' SORT el.email.sendAfter LIMIT 1 RETURN el",
      bindVars: {
        "@collection": "my-collection"
      }
    })
    .then(cursor => cursor.all());
}
```

But I want to move the top code out to another file and just require db and collection, how do I make that work? Have been struggling to make it work for too long now.

```js
const {
  db,
  collection
} = require("./db");

const getJobFromQueue = () => {
  return db.query({
      query: "FOR el IN @@collection FILTER DATE_TIMESTAMP(el.email.sendAfter) < DATE_NOW() AND el.status != 'processed' AND el.status != 'failed' SORT el.email.sendAfter LIMIT 1 RETURN el",
      bindVars: {
        "@collection": "my-collection"
      }
    })
    .then(cursor => cursor.all());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do exactly what you proposed. move the upper part of your code to `db.js` and expose `db`and `collection` using `exports`:

**db.js:**

```
const {
    Database
} = require("arangojs");
  
var db = new Database({
    url: "http://localhost:8529"
});

const database_name = "cool_database";  
db.useBasicAuth("username", "password123");
db.listDatabases()
  .then(names => {
    if (names.indexOf(database_name) > -1) {
      db.useDatabase(database_name);
      db.get();
    } else {
      db.createDatabase(database_name)
        .then(() => {
          db.useDatabase(database_name);
          db.collection("my-collection").create();
        });
    }
  });

exports.collection = db.collection("my-collection");
exports.db = db;
```

**index.js:**

```
const {
  db,
  collection
} = require("./db");

const getJobFromQueue = () => {
  return db.query({
      query: "FOR el IN @@collection FILTER DATE_TIMESTAMP(el.email.sendAfter) < DATE_NOW() AND el.status != 'processed' AND el.status != 'failed' SORT el.email.sendAfter LIMIT 1 RETURN el",
      bindVars: {
        "@collection": "my-collection"
      }
    })
    .then(cursor => cursor.all());
}
```

**WARNING**:

keep in mind, there is a potential race condition in your code. you may end up using `db` and `collection`, before they hat been initialized.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why this wouldn't work for me earlier :) Do you have any tip on how to fix the problem with the race condition?

Comment: you are welcome. Instead of exporting `collection`, you can export a Promise providing you with `collection` once it is ready. You already do something similar using `db.listDatabases().then(...)`. Take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49033851/804521) on how Promise works.